# Need to block subdomain using robots.txt which is on same directory level

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have one problem

I have domain name for example `www.testing.com` and `new.testing.com` so i do not want to new.testing.com display in any search engine. I have added one robots.txt to the new.testing.com. And both site has same parent directory

```
--httpdoc
----testing.com
----new.testing.com
```

So i want to know that can i handle both site using one robots.txt of testing.com is it possible???

Please suggest me solution if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best thing you could do is to add separate robots.txt files. Put one in each directory. You should have

- testing.com/robots.txt and
- new.testing.com/robots.txt

After adding robots.txt file to new.testing.com, you should add following code to keep search engines away.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: if domain and subdomain same directory how can disallow only subdomain?

disallow: /new.domain.com/ that true? or have any another idea? please help...

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.website.com$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-subdomain.txt
```

Then add the following to /robots-subdomain.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following rules inside  works for me,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/robots.txt$ /nobots.txt [L]
```

And add 'nobots.txt' to root directory as follows,

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```